# issue with loading events in js

Tags: javascript

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", handler, false);
    document.addEventListener("readystatechange", handler, false);
    window.addEventListener("load", handler, false);
} else if (document.attachEvent) {
    document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", handler);
    window.attachEvent("onload", handler);
}
```

Above codes is taken from a site.

Questions:

1. why for `DOMContentLoaded` and  `readystatechange`, we use  `document.addEventListener();` while load, we use `window.addEventListener()`, why?
2. For `readystatechange`, we can use in IE this way:`document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", handler);`, how aobut `DOMContentLoaded`? is there a way that we can use it in IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Context, who owns the events you are trying to listen. You don't listen for events on `<button>` elements when you want to listen to `<input>` elements :D
2. [`DOMContentLoaded` is supported natively in IE9+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded#Browser_compatibility). Prior to IE9, `readystatechange` can be used.